# Django CSRF token error when Chrome developer tools is open

Tags: django, google-chrome, django-csrf

I've been getting a very strange issue with Chrome only the last few days and I cannot pinpoint what had gone wrong. Essentially, I'm getting a consistent `CSRF` error on form submissions ***only*** when the developer tools panel is open. I do not get the error when the panel is closed. This makes debugging certain things nigh on impossible.

There have been no changes to the `middleware` or `CSRF` token handling that I'm aware of (I'm not the only dev on the project, but I have sense checked the commits). The version of Chrome is 71 (released December 4th, long before this started happening), so I doubt it's specific to the browser.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has experienced anything similar?

The Django error is:

```
Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed.
Request aborted.
Reason given for failure: CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

Comment: Try to clean browser data and cache.

Comment: If clean browser data and cache didn't work, can you post your relevant code? It could be that something is slightly off

Comment: Clearing browser data and cache does not solve the issue. I'm not sure which code is relevant yet, but we are chasing a lead on whether a new authentication procedure (outside of django) is causing the problem.

Comment: Looks like it is actually a recent upgrade of a python package, but not sure yet which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Katharine, have you been able to identify/solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry this was a year ago and I don't remember what the solution was, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with google chrome after manually deleting the crsf cookie regardless of having developer tools open or not.

The problem for me was in settings.py:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

This makes it fail under development because the browser will only accept the cookie over an https connection. So setting CRSF_COOKIE_SECURE to false (default) solved my issue.

Relevant docs section: [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#s-csrf-cookie-secure)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I do that in my code to solved it : I test it in Chrome and Firefox

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    SERVER_RUN = 'cloud'
    DEBUG = False
else:
    SERVER_RUN ='local'
    DEBUG = True
    
if SERVER_RUN !='local':
    SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.mywebsite.com'
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
else:
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```